# StackExchange web sites DOWN

Tags: discussion

are all StackExchange sites DOWN.

Lost all profile information, the scores ect.. on multiple pages

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they're back up since you were able to ask a question.

I don't see anything in your profile that indicates a problem so you'll need to be more specific about what's going on before we can help you.

Comment: My multiple profiles on multiple sites were purged. Lost my membership and all credits. Posting now as new user.

Comment: Coincidently it happen after I joined the Woodworking site ?

Comment: Showing only messages from 2013 on Ask Different, no points, where I had 45k, asks me to log in as NEW user

Comment: Can you find and link any of your old posts? Do you know what any of your account IDs (numeric) were? What were the account names?

Comment: Looks like you've created a new account on woodworking, and are now starting to login to sites with that account instead of your main account. I'll submit a merge request to join your accounts, but it may go quicker if you submit a request to [merge your accounts](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A site going down doesn't destroy all your progression on it.

However, what you may not realize is that StackExchange (and many other sites) allow you to have an informal quasi-account based on **web browser "cookies"**. You know, those shady things associated with ad targeting and loss of privacy.

However, cookies are unique to each web browser on each physical PC. Firefox / your 2019 Dell has a different cookie than Chrome/2019 Dell and also Safari/2021 iPhone.  So you can't switch PCs or even browsers.

What's more, most support folks advise to clear cookies often, to reduce ad tracking. Or simply to improve performance - my sweetie's Firefox no longer takes 5 minutes to start, now that I deleted 8 years (4 gigs) of cache, cookies and history. But that destroys quasi-accounts.

So you are better off moving up to some sort of sign-in.

- (better) [Register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) with a **Facebook or Google sign-in**.  This uses OpenID/OAuth (or in Facebook's case a proprietary system) to log in. However, it locks you into that platform, so you can't quit, and they track your activities so there goes your privacy.  Worse, say the wrong thing on the platform, get banned, and now you can't log into anything!
- (best) [Register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) with an **email/username/password**.  This is the most reliable (and private) but requires you to track passwords in a password manager or giant spreadsheet full of obscure hints. I have over 200 such IDs and I really resist it - it would be much worse if I set up an account for every site which encouraged me to!

This happens *a lot* on StackExchange because of their (dumb?) policy of allowing cookie logins... but fortunately StackExchange has the ability to "merge accounts". Not all sites do.

I will say cookie accounts (every visitor gets one) are less hostile than the "you MUST tie to Facebook/Google to even see our content" approach of Quora, Zulily, and many others.